# How to make a declared module visible in Enzyme shallow render?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, jestjs, enzyme

I've been trying to figure out how to have my declared module be found when I shallow render a component using enzyme in my jest unit tests. I have a custom declared module like so:

```
// index.d.ts
declare module "_aphrodite" {
    import {StyleDeclarationValue} from "aphrodite";

    type CSSInputType = StyleDeclarationValue | false | null | void;

    interface ICSSInputTypesArray extends Array<CSSInputTypes> {}

    export type CSSInputTypes = CSSInputType | CSSInputType[] | ICSSInputTypesArray;
}
```

Which is used by a component of mine called closeButton:

```
// closeButton.tsx
import {CSSInputTypes} from "_aphrodite";

export interface ICloseButtonProps {
  onClick: (event: React.MouseEvent<HTMLDivElement, MouseEvent>) => void;
  cssStyles?: CSSInputTypes;
}

@injectable()
@observer
@autobind
export class CloseButton extends React.Component<ICloseButtonProps> {
    // implementation
}
```

And a simple unit test that shallow renders a component:

```
// closeButton.test.tsx
import {shallow} from "enzyme";
import {CloseButton} from "../../common";
import * as React from "react";

describe("Common - Close Button", () => {
  it("Shallow Render", () => {
    const component = shallow(<CloseButton onClick={null}/>);

    console.log(component);
  });
});
```

When I run the test, I get the following error:

[image]

Which is strange because the closeButton class doesn't throw any compilation errors and maps the module fine. Same goes with when I run my project locally, it doesn't throw any run time error about not being able to find the _aphrodite module. It seems it's just with testing that this comes up.

Now I've tried to change various settings in my jest.config.json, tsconfig.json, and webpack.config.js settings with no luck. I'm hoping someone with more experience than I would know what needs to be done in order to make my _aphrodite module found when running a shallow render on a component.

Below are the settings for the aforementioned files:

```
// jest.config.json
{
  "verbose": true,
  "moduleFileExtensions": [
    "ts",
    "tsx",
    "js"
  ],
  "moduleDirectories": [
    "node_modules",
    "src"
  ],
  "moduleNameMapper": {
    "\\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|svg)$": "<rootDir>/src/components/__tests__/_transformers/fileTransformer.js"
  },
  "transform": {
    "\\.(ts|tsx)$": "ts-jest"
  },
  "setupFiles": [
    "<rootDir>/src/components/__tests__/setup.ts"
  ],
  "testRegex": "(/__tests__/\\.*|(\\.|/)(test))\\.tsx?$",
  "testURL": "http://localhost/",
  "collectCoverage": false,
  "timers": "fake"
}

// tsconfig.json
{
  "compileOnSave": true,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "rootDir": "./src",
    "outDir": "./build/",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "target": "es2018",
    "jsx": "react",
    "watch": false,
    "removeComments": true,
    "preserveConstEnums": true,
    "inlineSourceMap": false,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "es2018",
      "esnext"
    ],
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "isolatedModules": false
  },
  "include": [
    "./src/**/*"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "./node_modules"
  ]
}

// webpack.config.js
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");
const webpack = require('webpack');
const dotenv = require('dotenv');
const fs = require('fs'); // to check if the file exists

module.exports = () => {

  return {
    plugins: []
  };
};

/**
 * DevServer
 */
const devServer = {
  inline: true,
  host: "localhost",
  port: 3000,
  stats: "errors-only",
  historyApiFallback: true,
  watchOptions: {
    poll: true
  },
};

module.exports.getEnv = () => {
  // Create the fallback path (the production .env)
  const basePath = __dirname + '/.env';

  // We're concatenating the environment name to our filename to specify the correct env file!
  const envPath = basePath + ".local";

  // Check if the file exists, otherwise fall back to the production .env
  const finalPath = fs.existsSync(envPath) ? envPath : basePath;

  // call dotenv and it will return an Object with a parsed key
  const finalEnv = dotenv.config({path: finalPath}).parsed;

  // reduce it to a nice object, the same as before
  const envKeys = Object.keys(finalEnv).reduce((prev, next) => {
    prev[`process.env.${next}`] = JSON.stringify(finalEnv[next]);
  return prev;
}, {});
  return new webpack.DefinePlugin(envKeys);
};

/**
 * Plugins
 */
const plugins = [
  new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
    template: "./index.html"
  }),
  module.exports.getEnv()
];

module.exports = {
  entry: "./src/index.tsx",
  output: {
    filename: "bundle.js",
    path: __dirname + "/build",
    publicPath: "/"
  },

  // Enable sourcemaps for debugging webpack's output.
  devtool: "source-map",

  resolve: {
    // Add '.ts' and '.tsx' as resolvable extensions.
    extensions: [".ts", ".tsx", ".js", ".json"]
  },

  module: {
    rules: [
      // All files with a '.ts' or '.tsx' extension will be handled by 'ts-loader'.
      {test: /\.tsx?$/, loader: "ts-loader"},

      // All output '.js' files will have any sourcemaps re-processed by 'source-map-loader'.
      {enforce: "pre", test: /\.js$/, loader: "source-map-loader", exclude: [/node_modules/, /build/, /__test__/]},

      {test:/\.css$/, use:['style-loader','css-loader'] },

      {test:/\.(png|svg)$/, loader: "url-loader"},

      {test:/\.mp3$/, loader: "url-loader" }
    ]
  },
  plugins: plugins,
  devServer: devServer,
  mode: "development",
  performance: {
    hints: false
  }
};
```

And here is my project structure:

[image]

Feel free to ask if more information is needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out I just needed to add it to the list of setup files in jest.config.json

```
// jest.config.json
"setupFiles": [
  "<rootDir>/src/components/__tests__/setup.ts",
  "<rootDir>/src/aphrodite/index.ts"
],
```